# Multiple Functions in Powershell Script

Tags: function, powershell

I have a powershell script that has 3 functions.
function1
function2
function3

By default, will function two begin only when function 1 ends?  Will function 3 only begin when function 2 ends?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by begin and end. If you mean the code that defines one function vs. another then that is controlled by the closing curly brace for the function }. If you mean code execution then unless you force execution to be asynchronous, all code is executed synchronously. So one line of code typically completes before the next line starts.

Comment: Couldn't you write a simple test script to figure this out yourself?

Comment: I think I found the answer - use a workflow with sequencing.  what I'm trying to accomplish is pretty simple - function1 (check and modify registry), function2 (install software after function1) and function3 (modify registry after function 2). I have written the functions and tested them in the script but just need to be sure they run in sequence and don't step on each other.

Comment: I did write the script, @KenWhite White.  I just was wondering if there was a defined order of execution.

Comment: ??  Functions execute .. when you call them ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler is right unless you are calling something a function that is not actually a function. It would be better if you were to post your code or an example of it. [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @allenr74 I would avoid using workflows they are old technology that will not be brought over to the next version of powershell (6/core) [breaking-changes](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/BREAKINGCHANGES.md). If you are a looking to run thing async, look at runspaces, if you are looking to run things remotely, look into pssession and `invoke-command`.

Answer (score 3):

To put the comments of this post into a summary, functions only run as you call them, see below.

```
### Functions ###

function function1 {
    write-host "function 1 is executing"
}

function function2 {
    write-host "function 2 is executing"
}

function function3 {
    write-host "function 3 is executing"
}

### Start of process ###

function3
function2
function1
```

If you saved the above code as `script.ps1` and ran it inside of a PowerShell console then this below would be the output.

```
PS C:/>.\script.ps1
function 3 is executing
function 2 is executing
function 1 is executing
```

`function3` will complete in it's entirety before `function2` will begin, same with `function2` and `function1`

I hope this helps you to understand how functions work and how to write and/or call them inside of a powershell script (.ps1 file)

Answer (score 0):

no, no, they are not. If the functions are complex and take longer to run, let say function one connects to https://server1 count oranges. Then functon2 connects to https://server2 count apples, then you will see
"connected to oranges server"
"count of apples is 25"
"Function 1 completed"
then you see connected to apples server
count of oranges 20millions
Function 2 completed.

I am not counting apples, but "files", but the output is mixed one doesn't wait the other finished. So I have to run manually one and after it finished run second because PS doesn't know when one is finished to run the second. I tried sleep, but you newer know on the internet connection to time them.

I need to count files and processes on different server so they match for failover.
Maybe I need to write all the stats to variables, and then output after all finished, but there are too much to do so.

-=-=-update=-=-=
In my case I figured out that different type of output to console make the mess.

`write-host "Apples count: " $countApples`

// the above line will be after the line

`"Oranges count: " + $countOranges`

So we have to use either all output to console as "Write-host" or all without write-host to make it looks good.